# How to create a whitelist on the Central device (Bluetooth)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, whitelist, nrf51

I want to create a whitelist on the Central device. Because there is a lot of peripheral devices around and I just want to connect one peripheral device. First I register the address of the central device to the peripheral device. When I work with a single peripheral device and a single central device, connection establishes and I can send commands from the central device to the peripheral device. But when I have more than one peripheral device in the vicinity, I can not send commands to the peripheral device registered from the central device. So I decided to create whitelist on the central device to connect the peripheral device which I registered before. But I don't know how to create a whitelist on the Central device. Do you have any example? (except ble_app_hrs)

Comment: Normally your central would scan for a device advertising the service in which it is interested.  You then display a list of the discovered devices to the user and they select the device to connect to.  You can then store that device's identifier in order to connect to it in the future.

Comment: Yes central device can connectto  the peripheral device. I want to get "ble_gap_addr_t" automatically after the connection is established. Then I want to store this address into whitelist. So I will only need to connect once to add peripheral addresses into the whitelist. Briefly, how to store ble_gap_addr_t and ble_gap_irk_t into whitelist?